# Integrate different xaml pages with mainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.
I wanted to reuse some part of the page on different pages of my application so I developed those pages on user control wpf xaml..
Can you please help or suggest some example on how to integrate different xaml pages to mainWindow.xaml so as to run my application.

Comment: This comes down to how to create instances of UserControls, which is trivial.

Comment: Right click on your project, add item, UserControl

Answer (score 0):

> so I developed those pages on user control wpf xaml

Here is a design philosophy, place all those user controls on the page in a common frame/location, then in the VM create an enum which will define the different states of the page which directly relate to each control.

Bind all the controls visibility to a property on the VM which identifies the current state (from the aforementioned state enum) and then using a converter hide or show the control.

---

Here is an example, place the enum on the VM class.

```
  public enum Operations
  {
     Authentication    = -1,
     DisplayResults    = 0,
     EditData,
     ...
  }
```

Create a property which will define the current state on the VM

```
public Operations CurrentState
{
    get { return _CurrentState; }
    set { _CurrentState = value; PropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Then on the control bind to that state, but also pass in text to identify the control

```
<controls:Authentication 
             Visibility="{Binding CurrentState, 
                                  ConverterParameter=Authentication, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource StateToVisiblity}}"/>
```

Then in our converter reference the enums and based on the current state determine whether the control should be shown or not:

```
public class OperationStateToVisiblity : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value != null)     && 
               (parameter != null) &&
                value.ToString().Equals(parameter.ToString())
            ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That way each control only is shown when the state changes and that control is defined to a specific enum.